# How to create an Information box on mouseover with CSS?

Tags: css, mouseover

How can I create an information box on mouseover using CSS?

This is the code that I have wrote, it work ok in all browser except on ie 11 and bellow, where the information box is shown only partially inside the surface of the button

```css
button.info {
  position: relative;
  top: 10em;
}
button.info span {
  display: none;
}
button.info:hover span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 1.5em;
  z-index: 6;
  width: 10em;
  border: 0.2em solid #535757;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
button.info:hover span:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -0.5em;
  width: 0.5em;
  height: 0.5em;
  border-bottom: 0.2em solid #535757;
  border-right: 0.2em solid #535757;
  left: 4%;
  margin-left: -0.2em;
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  z-index: 6;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="info">mouse over<span><p>More information</p></span>
</button>
```

**Update for the Problem description:**
The failure mode on IE occurs with the button tag. If the button tag is replaced for a div tag, it works ok.

Comment: Works for me in IE11

Comment: Do you have any other CSS properties on `button`? I've a hunch you may have an `overflow` property or even something overruling its `position` attribute.

Comment: No, I am trying this code alone with no other CSS code than this and it display the same problem on ie: the information box is shown only partially inside the surface of the button...

Comment: In which case, have a play with `overflow` as it might just be that IE is doing something strange by default.